# Tikzstyle for 2:1 Mux

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Could someone help me with a `\tikzstyle` for this trapezium block:

[image]

I tried but look how it looks like:

[image]

The main problem it is in how to set the text (0 1) in the right place.

The code I'm using to `\tikzstyle` and \node it is presented below:

```
\tikzstyle{mux} = [ trapezium,   draw,   
                    rotate = 270, trapezium angle = 60,  
                    minimum height = 1em,
                    inner ysep=10pt, outer sep=1pt, inner xsep=1pt, 
                    text width = 1em, 
                    node distance=3cm, text badly centered ]

 \node [mux, above of=sum1,align=center] (mux11)
                {\begin{large}\begin{sideways}0\end{sideways}\begin{sideways}\medskip 1\end{sideways}\end{large}};
```

I'm trying to draw a digital datapath so I'll use this block many times.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `sideways` inside the node, you can just rotate the border of the shape instead. Further, with `text width` defined, the node contents will be flush left, so by removing `text badly centered` they end up at the right place. This also allows you to use `\\` to add a line break. Last, don't use `\large` etc. as environments, you can specify the font size with `font=\large` in the style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{mux} = [ trapezium,   draw,   
                    shape border rotate = 270, trapezium angle = 60,  
                    inner ysep=0pt, outer sep=1pt, inner xsep=1pt, 
                    text width = 3em, 
                    node distance=3cm, font=\large ]

 \node [mux] {0\\1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way with Torbjørn's style but without `\tikzstyle`, in a slightly different syntax:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[ mux/.style = {trapezium, draw,   
                     shape border rotate = 270, trapezium angle = 60,  
                     inner ysep = 0pt, outer sep = 1pt, inner xsep = 1pt, 
                     text width = 3em, node distance = 3cm, font = \large} ]
  \node [mux] {0\\1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And that syntax with the newer and recommended `\tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{ mux/.style = { trapezium, draw,   
                         shape border rotate = 270, trapezium angle = 60,  
                         inner ysep = 0pt, outer sep = 1pt, inner xsep  =1pt, 
                         text width = 3em, node distance = 3cm, font  =\large} }
```

See also: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)